# Script to download a web page

Tags: linux, bash, webserver

i made a web server to show my page locally, because is located in a place with a poor connection so what i want to do is download the page content and replace the old one, so i made this script running in background but i am not very sure if this will work 24/7 (the 2m is just to test it, but i want it to wait 6-12 hrs), so, **¿what do you think about this script? is insecure? or is enough for what i am doing?** Thanks.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=1;
while [ $a -eq 1 ]
do
echo "Starting..."
sudo wget http://www.example.com/web.zip  --output-document=/var/www/content.zip
sudo unzip -o /var/www/content.zip -d /var/www/
sleep 2m
done
exit
```

UPDATE: This code i use now:
(Is just a prototype but i pretend not using sudo)

```
#!/bin/bash
a=1;
echo "Start"
while [ $a -eq 1 ]
do
echo "Searching flag.txt"
if [ -e flag.txt ]; then
    echo "Flag found, and erasing it"
    sudo rm flag.txt

    if [ -e /var/www/content.zip ]; then
    echo "Erasing old content file"
        sudo rm /var/www/content.zip
    fi
    echo "Downloading new content"
    sudo wget ftp://user:password@xx.xx.xx.xx/content/newcontent.zip  --output-document=/var/www/content.zip
    sudo unzip -o /var/www/content.zip -d /var/www/
    echo "Erasing flag.txt from ftp"
    sudo ftp -nv < erase.txt
    sleep 5s
else
    echo "Downloading flag.txt"
    sudo wget ftp://user:password@xx.xx.xx.xx/content/flag.txt
    sleep 5s
fi
echo "Waiting..."
sleep 20s

done
exit 0
```

erase.txt

```
open xx.xx.xx.xx
user user password
cd content
delete flag.txt
bye
```

Comment: Don't run wget and unzip as root.  Instead, set the permissions on /var/www so that the use this script runs as can access the files it needs to.  You should also consider using the system cron facility instead of a loop to do the scheduling.   see "man crontab" for more info.

Comment: agree with above comments. Also search here on S.O. for many *nix crontab questions asking very similar questions. Good luck.

Comment: Have you thought of using [`rsync`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)?

Comment: Nope, but it looks nice so i will try using it. The internet connection is very poor(3G) because the system will be located in a remote place so i just wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: I've added an answer that provides some tips on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `unzip`ping the new version of your content overtop the old may not be the best solution.  What if you remove a file from your site?  The local copy will still have it.  Also, with a zip-based solution, you're copying EVERY file each time you make a copy, not just the files that have changed.

I recommend you use `rsync` instead, to synchronize your site content.

If you set your local documentroot to something like `/var/www/mysite/`, an alternative script might then look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

logtag="`basename $0`[$$]"

logger -t "$logtag" "start"

# Build an array of options for rsync
#
declare -a ropts
ropts=("-a")
ropts+=(--no-perms --no-owner --no-group)
ropts+=(--omit-dir-times)
ropts+=("--exclude ._*")
ropts+=("--exclude .DS_Store")

# Determine previous version
#
if [ -L /var/www/mysite ]; then
    linkdest="$(stat -c"%N" /var/www/mysite)"
    linkdest="${linkdest##*\`}"
    ropts+=("--link-dest '${linkdest%'}'")
fi

now="$(date '+%Y%m%d-%H:%M:%S')"

# Only refresh our copy if flag.txt exists
#
statuscode=$(curl --silent --output /dev/stderr --write-out "%{http_code}" http://www.example.com/flag.txt")
if [ ! "$statuscode" = 200 ]; then
    logger -t "$logtag" "no update required"
    exit 0
fi

if ! rsync "${ropts[@]}" user@remoteserver:/var/www/mysite/ /var/www/"$now"; then
    logger -t "$logtag" "rsync failed ($now)"
    exit 1
fi

# Everything is fine, so update the symbolic link and remove the flag.
#
ln -sfn /var/www/mysite "$now"
ssh user@remoteserver rm -f /var/www/flag.txt

logger -t "$logtag" "done"
```

This script uses a few external tools that you may need to install if they're not already on your system:

- rsync, which you've already read about,
- curl, which could be replaced with wget .. but I prefer curl
- logger, which is probably installed in your system along with syslog or rsyslog, or may be part of the "unix-util" package depending on your Linux distro.

`rsync` provides a lot of useful functionality.  In particular:

- it tries to copy *only what has changed*, so that you don't waste bandwidth on files that are the same,
- the `--link-dest` option lets you refer to previous directories to create "links" to files that have not changed, so that you can have multiple copies of your directory with only single copies of unchanged files.

In order to make this go, both the `rsync` part and the `ssh` part, you will need to set up SSH keys that allow you to connect without requiring a password.  That's not hard, but if you don't know about it already, it's the topic of a different question .. or a simple search with your favourite search engine.

You can run this from a crontab every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * /path/to/thisscript
```

If you want to run it more frequently, note that the "traffic" you will be using for every check that does *not* involve an update is an HTTP GET of the flag.txt file.

Comment: Thanks you very much. But i have a question: if you synchronize, for example, the folder where is the "index.html", and you upload a new version, the old is overwritten or modified?. I ask you that because i had a trouble with the browser i am using, because in some instance, when i overwrite the index file, it just erases the old one to copy the new, and the system shows a failure because the system does not have any file, and then when the new one is copied, the system doesn't reload and stay blank

Comment: Check the `rsync` man page for how the `--link-dest` option works. The idea here is that you'll keep a single master version of your site on the remote server, and then use rsync to maintain "incremental" copies. So if you update index.html on the server, your next rsync will put the new index.html into the dated directory on your client machine, and the symlink will point to the new location.

Comment: For issues with your browser "noticing" that the file has been updated, you may be able to disable the cache in your browser, or explore HTTP headers in your web server like "Expires" or "ETag" or "Cache-Control". How you solve that will depend on your web server and browser, and is the subject of a different question.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest setting up a cron job, this is much more reliable than a script with huge `sleep`s.

Brief instructions:

If you have write permissions for `/var/www/`, simply put the downloading in your personal crontab.
Run `crontab -e`, paste this content, save and exit from the editor:

```
17 4,16 * * * wget http://www.example.com/web.zip --output-document=/var/www/content.zip && unzip -o /var/www/content.zip -d /var/www/
```

Or you can run the downloading from system crontab.
Create file `/etc/cron.d/download-my-site` and place this content into in:

```
17 4,16 * * * <USERNAME> wget http://www.example.com/web.zip --output-document=/var/www/content.zip && unzip -o /var/www/content.zip -d /var/www/
```

Replace `<USERNAME>` with a login that has suitable permissions for `/var/www`.

Or you can put all the necessary commands into single shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
wget http://www.example.com/web.zip --output-document=/var/www/content.zip
unzip -o /var/www/content.zip -d /var/www/
```

and invoke it from crontab:

```
17 4,16 * * * /path/to/my/downloading/script.sh
```

This task will run twice a day: at 4:17 and 16:17. You can set another schedule if you'd like.

More on cron jobs, crontabs etc:

- [Add jobs into cron](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/)
- [CronHowto on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)
- [Cron(Wikipedia)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)